# How to remove three dots (...) at the end of post thumbnail on blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove three dots (...) at the end of post thumbnail (See Below image) on blogger. Please help me. Thanks.
[three dots (...) at the end of post thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emZ58.png)

Comment: Why? The "three dots" mean that there is more to the article. Without them the sentence makes no sense.

Comment: Dear Sir, I want to Remove only  "three dots" in my post thumbnail. do you know about Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Target the element containing the text with jQuery and use `String.replace` to remove the dots from the text.

Comment: Dear Sir, I don’t have sound Knowledge in JavaScript or jQuery. I give my post thumbnail JavaScript below. Can you change it to Without Three dots? Thank you for Response to my Question.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByuGuHHrxa5GWU5IN2psQkQzaHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Dear Sir, I don’t have sound Knowledge in JavaScript or jQuery. I give my post thumbnail JavaScript below. Can you change it to Without Three dots? Thank you for Response to my Question.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByuGuHHrxa5GWU5IN2psQkQzaHM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can try using jquery. So your paragraph that only contain '...' will be alter.

```
$("p:contains('...')").each(function() {
   var text = $(this).text();
   $(this).text(text.replace('...', '')); 
});
```

Comment: Dear Sir, I don’t have sound Knowledge in JavaScript or jQuery. I give my post thumbnail JavaScript below. Can you change it to Without Three dots? Thank you for Response to my Question.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByuGuHHrxa5GWU5IN2psQkQzaHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Dear Sir, Your method isn't working. I have Given my post thumbnail JavaScript below. Please Check the JavaScript code and Let me know how to change it. Please help me. Thanks.
JavaScript URL: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByuGuHHrxa5GWU5IN2psQkQzaHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: no. it is not mine. I gave that image for Example about three dots (...)